# How to install dll into GAC.

Tags: .net, gac

I have to install the DLL to GAC. I have checked that same DLL is present there in the GAC related to my project. Is my steps correct?

1: Uninstall the previous DLL by clicking on File > Uninstall Assembly
2: Open Visual Studio command prompt
3: Type this `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322> gacutil.exe \i C:\xyz\My project\Projectxyz.dll`

OR

Drag and drop the DLL from Bin to GAC ?

Is it mandatory to give the strong name to the assembly or can I avoid it? What is the side effect if I don't give the strong name?

Comment: The dll has to be strong named to be added in the GAC.

Comment: @NLV When I created my project in Visual Studio and build it I got the DLL. Is it not strong named ?

Comment: No, it isn't strong named. Look at Project -> Properties -> Signing, "Sign the assembly" option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your last question, **yes**, you must strong-name your assembly in order to install it into the GAC.

Something tells me that you don't really need to add your assembly to the GAC.  Only in very few cases is there a benefit to doing this.  Unless you know what these cases are, and know they apply to you, I'd suggest you forget about it.

Comment: Can you outline the cases you mention in your answer? Please and thank you.

Comment: Here are some - If the DLL is shared by more than one application, if the dll needs full trust, if you want to maintain multiple versions of dll at the same time (by different applications).

Comment: @Anna NLV is right.  I'd say that the two major reasons for doing it is that you have multiple appdomains in which you use the same assembly (strong named assemblies are shared across appdomains) and you expect to have two different versions of the same assembly loaded in memory.